# Why has my Yahoo Mail account been compromised?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I found a post regarding [Yahoo Mail "Strongly Believed to Be Compromised"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15365/yahoo-mail-strongly-believed-to-be-compromised), and it was exactly my case. I logged into my Yahoo mail account from China and I received a security alert stating my account has been compromised.

Could you explain more why it happened?

Answer (score 2):

Since that's kind of hard to do without threatening legal action against Yahoo or a similar tactic, I'll just go over some of the more common ways that accounts are hijacked:

- The hacker installed malware on your computer, and it captured your password or a session cookie and went along and tried to change your password or something.
- The hacker created a phishing site and skimmed the password from you without you realizing that it was a fraudulent page.
- The hacker hacked into Yahoo's servers and grabbed their hashes and started cracking them.
- The hacker may have pulled the password from a recent [disclosure of passwords](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/technology/2011/06/lulzsec-publishes-62000-email-and-password-combinations.html).